# There's some error on my Flutter Local Notification

Tags: android, flutter, notifications

I need help, there's an error when calling Local Notification.

For the initState :

```
initState() {
    super.initState();
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    // initialise the plugin. app_icon needs to be a added as a drawable resource to the Android head project
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
        new AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
        initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin().initialize(initializationSettings, onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
  }
```

For the function :

```
showNotification() async {
    var android = new AndroidNotificationDetails('Channel ID', 'Channel Name', 'channelDescription');
    var iOS = new IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platform = new NotificationDetails(android, iOS);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0, 'New Notification', 'Flutter Local Notif', platform,payload: 'test notification');
  }
```

> The error is "PlatformException (PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference, null))"

I've already tried on the documentation and also youtube, but I always get this error message

Comment: so it's crashing on  "await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0, 'New Notification', 'Flutter Local Notif', platform,payload: 'test notification');"?Using the debugger and breakpoints can you see what value is coming back null?

Comment: So when i tried with breakpoint, the didReceiveLocalNotificationCallback was null, and on the _platform directory, the executable was null, executableArguments:List (0 items)

Answer (score 22):

I have faced this, and in my case it was an icon problem `app_icon`
in your `initState` function replace this

```
 var initializationSettingsAndroid = new AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
```

with this

```
 var initializationSettingsAndroid = new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Add your `app_icon.png` to `MY_PROJECT\android\app\src\main\res\drawable\app_icon.png`

However, for me the error was in androidInitialization. I was initializing it this way:

```
var androidInit = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon.png');
```

Here, the `.png` shouldn't be added. I know this might be silly but if it helps anyone out there facing the same problem then there you go! This is the **correct** method:

```
var androidInit = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
```

Comment: thank you. It's not silly. even i got the same issue

Answer (score 1):

this one works for me you can give a chance

```
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
to the Android head project
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
  }



  Future<void> _showNotification() async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'your channel id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description',
        importance: Importance.Max, priority: Priority.High, ticker: 'ticker');
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, 'plain title', 'plain body', platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: 'item x');
  }



 Future<void> onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      debugPrint('notification payload: ' + payload);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's an error when i'm using this code.
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder. The method 'initialize' was called on null.Receiver: null. Tried calling: initialize(Instance of 'InitializationSettings', onSelectNotification: Closure: (String) => Future<dynamic> from Function 'onSelectNotifications':.)

Comment: So after i clean and rebuild my app, there's a new error statement.
`E/flutter ( 8430): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'show' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 8430): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 8430): Tried calling: show(0, "plain title", "plain body", Instance of 'NotificationDetails', payload: "item x")`

Answer (score 1):

There is problem in your plugin initialization. I see in your code, you created the instance **flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin** but used **FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin().initialize()** instead. And then you tried to show notification with the created instance which has not been initialized.

I got this error for the same reason - my FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin was not initialized properly. To check if it is, I tried the below code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
  initializeNotification(); //Its Important to place this line after runApp() otherwise FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin will not be initialize and you will get the error as mentioned in the question.
}


void initializeNotification() async {
  try {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings, onSelectNotification: didSelectNotification);
  } catch(e) {
   print(e.toString());
  }
}
```

If it catch any exception, your flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin has not been initialized, and you will get an error.

Also try to wrap initialization code in separate async-await function.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I added `app_icon.png` to the android drawables, in this path : `MY_PROJECT\android\app\src\main\res\drawable`

Take a look at the source code here
https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/tree/master/flutter_local_notifications/example/android/app/src/main/res/drawable

Copy Paste all drawables to your project, it will work.

And **Don't Forget to add these receivers** to Manifest

```
<receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

for me adding `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` to main.dart before creating `AndroidInitializationSettings` helps.

Answer (score 0):

uture _requestPermissions() async {
const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');

```
/// Note: permissions aren't requested here just to demonstrate that can be
/// done later
final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
    DarwinInitializationSettings(
        requestAlertPermission: false,
        requestBadgePermission: false,
        requestSoundPermission: false,
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: (
          int id,
          String? title,
          String? body,
          String? payload,
        ) async {
          didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject.add(
            ReceivedNotification(
              id: id,
              title: title,
              body: body,
              payload: payload,
            ),
          );
        });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).