# How to solve flutter_local_notifications PlatformException error?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm using `flutter_local_notifications` package in a project for the first time.

Followed the codes given in the documentation in `pub.dev` site. But the problem is when I press the button that should trigger the notification it is causing a `PlatformException` error.

**The Error**

```
E/flutter (15180): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference, null)
E/flutter (15180): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
E/flutter (15180): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:318:33)
E/flutter (15180): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15180): #2      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show (package:flutter_local_notifications/src/flutter_local_notifications.dart:120:20)
E/flutter (15180): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15180): #3      _NewsfeedState.showNotification (package:news_app/screens/newsfeed_screen.dart:129:43)
```

The codes are given below.

**initState()**

```
  @override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();

    var android = AndroidInitializationSettings('mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png');
    var ios = IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initSettings = InitializationSettings(android, ios);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSettings, onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);

}
```

**onSelectNotification()** : It shows a Dialog box when the notification is pressed.

```
Future onSelectNotification(String payload) {
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Notfication"),
      content: Text("This is notification"),
    ));
  }
```

**Main widget** : I was using this `Press` button to check if the notification works, as a test purpose.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: showNotification,
          child: Text(
              "Press"
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

**showNotification()**

```
showNotification() async {
    var android = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'channel id',
        'channel NAME',
        'CHANNEL DESCRIPTION',
        importance: Importance.Max,
        priority: Priority.High,
        ticker: 'ticker'
    );
    var ios = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platform = NotificationDetails(android, ios);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(0, "New Notification", "I'm notification", 
    platform, payload: "It works");
  }
```

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56807107/9707804) that I found about this error, but the solution it provides was of no use for me.

I tried changing the version of the `flutter_local_notifications` package couple of times, did not work.

Then traced back the files that were shown in the error to see what exactly is causing `null` value.

In the file `platform_channel.dart`, inside the `invokeMethod<T>(String method, [dynamic arguments])` I tried to print the `method` and `arguments` to see what is coming out to be `null`. This method is called from `flutter_local_notifications.dart`.

**invokeMethod(String method, [ dynamic arguments ])**

```
 @optionalTypeArgs
  Future<T> invokeMethod<T>(String method, [ dynamic arguments ]) async {
    assert(method != null);
    final ByteData result = await binaryMessenger.send(
      name,
      codec.encodeMethodCall(MethodCall(method, arguments)),
    );

    print(arguments);  
    print(method); 

    if(result == null) {
      throw MissingPluginException('No implementation found for method $method on channel 
      $name');
    }
    final T typedResult = codec.decodeEnvelope(result);
    return typedResult;
  }
```

The output of arguments is,

`I/flutter (15180): {id: 0, title: New News!, body: I'm news., platformSpecifics: {icon: null, channelId: channel id, channelName: channel NAME, channelDescription: CHANNEL DESCRIPTION, channelShowBadge: true, channelAction: 0, importance: 5, priority: 1, playSound: true, sound: null, enableVibration: true, vibrationPattern: null, style: 0, styleInformation: {htmlFormatContent: false, htmlFormatTitle: false}, groupKey: null, setAsGroupSummary: null, groupAlertBehavior: 0, autoCancel: true, ongoing: null, colorAlpha: null, colorRed: null, colorGreen: null, colorBlue: null, largeIcon: null, largeIconBitmapSource: null, onlyAlertOnce: null, showProgress: false, maxProgress: 0, progress: 0, indeterminate: false, enableLights: false, ledColorAlpha: null, ledColorRed: null, ledColorGreen: null, ledColorBlue: null, ledOnMs: null, ledOffMs: null, ticker: ticker}, payload: I'm the one}`

You can see the `title`, `body`, `channel id`, `channel NAME` these are all the ones I gave but there are many other fields which are `null`. I'm guessing these to cause the error, but not certain.

As I followed the documentation, I did not see any instruction for such fields.

Some clue would mean great help. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: No, yet to solve.

Answer (score 3):

From plugin's [readme](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#-readme-tab-):

> *app_icon needs to be a added as a drawable resource to the Android head project*

So put your `app_icon` into `drawable` folder instead of `mipmap`, and change your code to:

```
var android = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
```

Answer (score 1):

In android project. Under the folder "res" you have an icon in the folder "mipmap/launcher_icon" like it is shown in this picture.
[Folder structue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmOIA.png)

In order to use it, you can set up the  AndroidNotificationDetails

```
 AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description',
    importance: Importance.max,
    priority: Priority.high,
    showWhen: false,
icon: "mipmap/launcher_icon"); //the important part
```

So just set the icon: **"mipmap/launcher_icon"** since that is the android resource name.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for me in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60236675/11192570

with this code:

```dart
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
          new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
      var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
          '1687497218170948721x8',
          'New Trips Notification ',
          'Notification Channel for vendor. All the new trips notifications will arrive here.',
          style: AndroidNotificationStyle.BigText,
          icon: "app_icon",
          styleInformation: BigTextStyleInformation(
            "hanji hogya?",//  'Locations: <b>${locations.replaceAll("\$", " to ")}</b><br>Vehicle: <b>$vehicle</b><br>Trip Type: <b>$tripType</b><br>Pick-Up Date: <b>$pickUpDate</b><br>Pick-Up Time: <b>$pickUpTime</b>',
              htmlFormatBigText: true,
              contentTitle: 'Amount:- <b>Rs 22000000</b>',
              htmlFormatContentTitle: true,
              summaryText: 'Trip Details',
              htmlFormatSummaryText: true));
```